# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl

Tags: centos

I'm trying to install a script on my server. But it doesn't finish the job at the last step.

```
./make.sh

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How do I fix above issue?

Centos 6.4 Final  x86_64

Comment: You need to install the `openssl-devel` package.

Comment: Thanks. I've installed openssl-devel and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

You need the install the open ssl developer package:

```
yum -y install openssl-devel
```

Comment: i have the same erorr but for -lz
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz

any idea what lib is missing?